# Convert JSON nested array to flat array

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON array which includes a nested array:

```json
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 659,
            "created_at": "2023-01-13T06:35:08.000000Z",
            "products": [
                {
                    "name": "532",
                    "properties": [
                        {
                            "name": "color",
                            "value": "blue"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "size",
                            "value": "1"
                        }
                    ],
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 658,
            "created_at": "2023-01-12T21:36:06.000000Z",
            "products": [
                {
                    "name": "532",
                    "properties": [
                        {
                            "name": "color",
                            "value": "khaki"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "size",
                            "value": "2"
                        }
                    ],
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 656,
            "created_at": "2023-01-11T17:19:42.000000Z",
            "products": [
                {
                    "name": "2245/442",
                    "properties": [
                        {
                            "name": "color",
                            "value": "gray"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "fabric",
                            "value": "fleece"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "size",
                            "value": "2"
                        }
                    ],
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 655,
            "created_at": "2023-01-10T21:56:51.000000Z",
            "products": [
                {
                    "name": "298/426-2",
                    "properties": [
                        {
                            "name": "color",
                            "value": "blue"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "fabric",
                            "value": "footer"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "size",
                            "value": "4"
                        }
                    ],
                },
                {
                    "name": "257/426",
                    "properties": [
                        {
                            "name": "color",
                            "value": "mint"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "fabric",
                            "value": "footer"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "size",
                            "value": "4"
                        }
                    ],
                }
            ]
        },
    ],
}
```

I need to read it and write it to another array. All code I have so far:

```js
var responce = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
var dataAll = JSON.parse(responce.getContentText());
var dataSet = dataAll.data;
var rows = [];

dataSet.forEach((e) => {
  e.products.forEach((product) => {
    product.properties.forEach((property) => {
      rows.push([e.id, e.created_at, product.name, property.value]);
    })
  });
});

console.log(rows);
```

It writes data to an array in the form, that is, for each "product.value" value, it writes "id", "created_at", "name":

```js
[ 659, '2023-01-13T06:35:08.000000Z', '532', 'blue' ],
[ 659, '2023-01-13T06:35:08.000000Z', '532', '1' ],
[ 658, '2023-01-12T21:36:06.000000Z', '532', 'khaki' ],
[ 658, '2023-01-12T21:36:06.000000Z', '532', '2' ],
[ 656, '2023-01-11T17:19:42.000000Z', '2245/442', 'gray' ],
[ 656, '2023-01-11T17:19:42.000000Z', '2245/442', 'fleece' ],
[ 656, '2023-01-11T17:19:42.000000Z', '2245/442', '2' ],
[ 655, '2023-01-10T21:56:51.000000Z', '298/426-2', 'blue' ],
[ 655, '2023-01-10T21:56:51.000000Z', '298/426-2', 'footer' ],
[ 655, '2023-01-10T21:56:51.000000Z', '298/426-2', '4' ],
[ 655, '2023-01-10T21:56:51.000000Z', '257/426', 'mint' ],
[ 655, '2023-01-10T21:56:51.000000Z', '257/426', 'footer' ],
[ 655, '2023-01-10T21:56:51.000000Z', '257/426', '4' ]
```

But I need to write like:

```js
[ 659, '2023-01-13T06:35:08.000000Z', '532', 'blue', '1' ],
[ 658, '2023-01-12T21:36:06.000000Z', '532', 'khaki', '2' ],
[ 656, '2023-01-11T17:19:42.000000Z', '2245/442', 'gray', 'fleece', '2' ],
[ 655, '2023-01-10T21:56:51.000000Z', '298/426-2', 'blue', 'footer', '4' ],
[ 655, '2023-01-10T21:56:51.000000Z', '257/426', 'mint', 'footer', '4' ]
```

That is, I need to read the array "properties" and write the values "values" to a string (maybe I'm not expressing myself correctly).
I understand that I need to use the "map" function, but I don't understand how to use it yet ((

Thanks in advance for any advice

Comment: Your JSON isn't valid. JSON doesn't allow trailing commas.

Answer (score 0):

```
dataSet.forEach((e) => {
   e.products.forEach((product) => {
     rows.push([
       e.id, e.created_at, product.name
     ].concat(product.properties.map(p => p.value)));
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The provided code achieves the desired output by transforming the given dataset into a new array called rows. It does so by iterating over each item in the dataset and extracting relevant information such as the "id" and "created_at" values.

For each item, the code further iterates over the products within that item. It retrieves the "name" of each product and extracts the values of its properties. By pushing these values into a new array, the code constructs a sub-array that represents a product with its corresponding values.

By repeating this process for each item and product, the code accumulates these sub-arrays into the rows array. As a result, the rows array contains sub-arrays in the desired format, consisting of the "id", "created_at", "name", and "product.value" values.

By employing the map() function and leveraging nested iterations, the code successfully transforms the original dataset into the desired output structure, providing an array that holds the necessary information for each product in a convenient format.

```
const rows = dataSet.map((item) => {
    const newRows = [item.id, item.created_at];
    item.products.forEach((product) => {
        const properties = product.properties.map((property) => property.value);
        newRows.push(product.name);
        newRows.push(...properties);
    });
    return newRows;
});

console.log(rows);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).